# Page doesn't load javascripts and css only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, browser-cache

When I am pressing back button I am getting cached site but only in Chrome. When I've tried on firefox everything was just fine.
I tried in javascript:

init:

```
window.onpopstate = handlePopstate;
```

function:

```
var handlePopstate = function(e) {
        if(e.state) {
            targets.$container.replaceWith(e.state.response);
        }
    };
```

Comment: clear browser history and cache and try again

Comment: I did it already, didn't help.